# insertAdjacentHTML with iframe turns the content into HTML entities

Tags: javascript, iframe, html-entities

I'm trying to insert a iframe at the end of an element using `insertAdjacentHTML`. But for some reason the content inside the iframe gets turned into HTML entities ("<" to &lt, ">" to &gt).

Why is this happening?

[Here's a fiddle](http://tinkerbin.com/kalcC63H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid `IFRAME` syntax. Take a look at this: http://tinkerbin.com/zz6MeNYW

`IFRAME` can only contain text, not HTML. Therefore it will convert the HTML to a string. 
Text inside the `IFRAME` is displayed if `IFRAME`s are not supported by the browser.

`IFRAME`s contents is defined by the `SRC` attribute.

The `insertAdjacentHTML` works with a `DIV` instead. See here: http://tinkerbin.com/sNLtSjE7

[Documentation on the IFRAME on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe)

**EDIT**

It seems you will be able to do what you want with the `SRCDOC` attribute in HTML 5. Check the MDN documentation (above). However, this seems not to be supported by any browsers yet.